# Docker services not resolving each other when recreated

Tags: docker, curl, docker-swarm

I have two swarm services which are started like this:

```
docker service create --replicas 2 \
--publish 8000 \
--network example \
--detach \
--name="user_service" example.com/user_service:prod

docker service create --replicas 2 \
--publish 8000 \
--network example \
--detach \
--name="company_service" example.com/company_service:prod
```

When I enter inside of `user_service` container and make request to `company_service`, I get this:

```
curl http://company_service:8000

# Returns
{"name": "Company Service"}
```

However, when I remove `company_service` like this

```
docker service rm company_service
```

Then recreate it with command at the beggining. When I try to make request from `user_service`, I get this:

```
curl http://company_service:8000

curl: (7) Failed to connect to company_service port 8000: Connection refused
```

How to force all existing services in same network to resolve again recreated service?

Comment: Please post the "recreate" example.

Comment: @opHASnoNAME   I run `docker service rm company_service` then run create for `company_service` as in the beginning of this post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attached "user_service" and "company_service" services to one network(overlay), then you can communicate with each other by their name.